# What is the best/suggested pythonic way (Ver: 2.7) to handle customization logic

Tags: python, python-2.7

My case is that:

```
def main():
    generic_process_000()
    generic_process_001()
    customized_process_000()
    generic_process_002()
```

As shown above, I need to implement a Python script that have some generic logic for all clients and some customization logic for specific clients.

What I want to do is that when running the Python script with client code as the command-line argument and the client code will determine what should be done at the customization logic "customized_process_000()"

I know that it can be achieved by simple if-then-else statement. But just want to find out if there are any better ways to do so. As the Admin does not like external libs, if possible, please suggest ways which can be done by built-in libs. But if not, external libs are also ok.

Highly appreciate if any simple code example can be provided together.

Comment: Is it just the `customized_process_000()` step which needs to be selected by a commans-line argument?

Comment: The logic should be within customized_process_000.

For example,  
`def customized_process_000(client_code):  
    if client_code == "ABC":  
        do something for ABC
    else:
        raise error`

Or

`def customized_process_000(client_code):
    if client_code in callable_dict:
        callable_dict[client_code]()
    else:
        raise error`

These are the simplest ways which can achieve what I want to do. But I am thinking if there is any better way to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you suggest: Having a `callable_dict` is the way to go:

```
def main(client_code):
    setup_callable_dict()
    generic_process_000()
    generic_process_001()
    customized_process_000(client_code)
    generic_process_002()


callable_dict = {}
def setup_callable_dict():
    callable_dict['foo'] = foo
    callable_dict['bar'] = bar
    callable_dict['zoo'] = zoo

def customized_process_000(client_code): 
    if client_code in callable_dict: 
        callable_dict[client_code]() 
    else: 
        raise error
```

**Update:**

In order to provide parameters from `generic_process_001()` and avoid global variables, these changes may help:

```
def main(client_code):
    callable_dict = setup_callable_dict()
    generic_process_000()
    result = generic_process_001()
    customized_process_000(callable_dict, client_code, result)
    generic_process_002()


def setup_callable_dict():
    callable_dict = {}
    callable_dict['foo'] = foo
    callable_dict['bar'] = bar
    callable_dict['zoo'] = zoo
    return callable_dict 

def customized_process_000(callable_dict, client_code, result): 
    if client_code in callable_dict: 
        callable_dict[client_code](result) 
    else: 
        raise error

def foo(result):
    expand, params, from, res = result
    #  carry on with foo
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let say the result from generic_process_001 is needed to pass to customized_process_000 for further processing. How can I force certain structure? Or this is not making sense in Python as it is not strongly typed? A dict declared at the outmost scope is ok? It is just like that I declare a global variable and use elsewhere, which may not be a good practice.

Comment: It looks like that the result you mean here is a tuple. Thanks for your update. Maybe I need to change my mind to use more dict and tuple.